# How to solve the Maven plugin issue in Intellij

Tags: maven-plugin

src\test\resources folder not created in maven project and showing error in maven plugins. how to resolve this issue in Intellij using windows.

i tried creating Maven project in Intellij and i expected to be created as Maven project Structure but in result src\test\resources folder not created and showing error in maven plugins also.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The Maven project structure itself is not created properly and while viewing Maven in IntelliJ it is showing an error for all plugins.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?